# Web-based log parser for real-time monitoring?

Tags: windows, performance, monitoring, log-files

Running Windows 2008.

I'm using Google Analytics which is perfect, except for:
 1. data is 24 hours old
 2. cannot monitor web services

My best solution is to use something like LogParser, which is excellent especially for forensic auditing. However, that requires me to download the log file. Which is (to me) a lot of work.

Is there a free web-based tool for log parsing? or will I end up creating a private ASP page that runs log parser with a specified query and writes back the result?

Comment: Shopping Questions are considered Off-Topic here on ServerFault.  Please see the [Help](http://serverfault.com/help) section or [Here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more info.  **If you are interested in having a way to ask these types of questions** head over to the [IT Shopping Questions Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59278/it-shopping-questions) and post your question as a possible question for the beta and follow the proposal.

Comment: @TheCleaner LOL. That question is more than four years ago.

Comment: yes I know.  It wasn't me that originally voted to close it, I simply added the comment during the Review.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the free version of [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/). It has a web interface and is basically real time for what you are looking for I think.  You can create your own custom searches to view the information you want, and it displays them on an interactive time line like Analytics does.

Answer (score 0):

IIS supports logging to an ODBC connection (i.e. a table in a SQL database) if you have the relevant options installed, so you could enable that in place of logging to file and create a series of reports that you can run against the resulting data.

It will probably buffer updates, as it does with file based logging, for efficiency but the results will probably be as close to real-time as makes no odds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want security monitoring of your web logs, I would suggest OSSEC. It monitors them in real time looking for attacks, errors, issues, etc (they call it LIDS - log-based intrusion detection).

Link: http://www.ossec.net